# Regular expression for matching time in military (24 hour) format

Tags: javascript, regex, time

I would like a JavaScript regular expression that will match time using the 24 hour clock, where the time is given with or without the colon.

For example, I would like to match time in the following formats:

- `0800`
- `23:45`
- `2345`

but that would not match invalid times such as

- `34:68`
- `5672`

Answer (score 134, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$
```

The expression reads:

```
^        Start of string (anchor)
(        begin capturing group
  [01]   a "0" or "1"
  \d     any digit
 |       or
  2[0-3] "2" followed by a character between 0 and 3 inclusive
)        end capturing group
:?       optional colon
(        start capturing
  [0-5]  character between 0 and 5
  \d     digit
)        end group
$        end of string anchor
```

Comment: 24:00 doesn't exist but is matched.  Change `[0-4]` to `[0-3]`.

Comment: or in the form:
^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):?([0-5][0-9])$
if you do not like the \d stuff :)

Comment: strager: 24:00 is perfectly valid, referring to the exact *end* of a day (and technically being the next day at 0:00). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_hour_time#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00

Comment: @strager—nor do 12pm and 12am, but people keep usint them… ;-)

Comment: Human friendly equivalent would be: `^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):?([0-5][0-9])$`

Answer (score 12):

```
/(00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23):?(0|1|2|3|4|5)\d/
```

:)

Comment: You didn't make the colon optional.

Comment: this answer is so much better than the accepted one. The accepted one ins unreadable without comments

Comment: That regex simplifies to: `/([01]\d|2[0-3]):?[0-5]\d/`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a better solution than the top one above for military plus a civilian solution.

Military

```
^(((([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3])):?[0-5][0-9])|(24:?00))
```

I believe the or in the highest rated response is not properly parsing the subsets before and after without the extra set of parenthesis to group them. Also, I'm not certain that the `\d` is just `0-9` in all iterations. It technically includes the special `[[:digit:]]` although I've never dealt with that being an issue before. Any how, this should provide every thing including the crossover 2400/24:00

Civilian

```
^([0-9]|([1][0-2])):[0-5][0-9][[:space:]]?([ap][m]?|[AP][M]?)
```

This is a nice Civilian version that allows for the full range formatted like 12:30PM, 12:30P, 12:30pm, 12:30p, 12:30 PM, 12:30 P, 12:30 pm, or 12:30 p but requires the morning or post meridian characters to be the same case if both are included (no Am or pM).

I use both of these in a bit of JavaScript to validate time strings.

Comment: Thanks, I like this one. I did add the $ at the end of it though. Also, I made the 0 optional at the beginning (i.e. 01:25 could be 1:25). Hopefully didn't mess anything up along the way. ^(((([0-1]?[0-9])|(2[0-3])):?[0-5][0-9])|(24:?00))$

Comment: The civilian one doesn't seem to work. If you throw it into http://regexr.com/ and try 12:30p, it returns no matches.

Comment: Works fine in regex101.com. Perhaps you misryped it instead of copy/paste? Regexr.com doesn't work on mobile devices or I would check.

Comment: There is no limit on the end of the regex, it will allow other characters to be entered at the end and still match, eg 13:4502938

Answer (score 2):

To keep the colon optional and allow all valid times:

```
([01]\d|2[0-3]):?[0-5]\d
```

Note that this assumes midnight will always be 0000 and never 2400.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a blog post, looking for the same thing](http://tgaw.wordpress.com/2007/03/15/javascript-regular-expression-for-military-time/) and a bunch of potential answers -- most of which don't work, but there is good discussion as to why each fails.

Of course, [explicitly long and accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494671/what-is-a-javascript-regular-expression-for-matching-time-in-military-24-hour-f/1494690#1494690) is always a possibility!

Comment: Yeah, he could just generate all possible times to an array (should be less than 16k), and then it is just a comparison =)

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I've just come up with:

```
(^((2[0-4])|([01]?[0-9])):[0-5][0-9]$)|(^((1[0-2])|(0?[1-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?)[pa]m$)
```

Accepts:

```
2pm
4:30am
07:05am
18:45
6:19
00:55
```

does not accept `00:05am` - I am not sure if there is such time as `0am`

If you feel that `:` is optional for 24h time format (military) - just add a question mark after it

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here's a regex I came up with which seems to work.

```
^(([[0|1]\d)|(2[0-3]))[:]?([0-5]\d)$
```

You can edit it [on this regex site](https://regex101.com/r/NGapBQ/1)

**Edit**
I just realised that this answer ended up exactly the same as the accepted answer but I will leave it here at least for the value of the 'do it yourself' link

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect:

```
^0?([0-9][0-2]?):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Note: 12 Hr Clock Only

For Times like:

```
0:01- 12:59
00:01 - 12:59
```

Comment: Sorry: This is the perfect one: (([0-9][0-2]?)|([0][0-9])):[0-5][0-9]$

Answer (score 0):

A human friendly version:

`^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):?([0-5][0-9])$`

Answer (score 0):

I've done this slightly differently to avoid the possibility of a single zero leading the time, like 0:45 vs 00:45. From what I can see, the more commonly used format allows for this technically incorrect format. Mine also prevents pattern matches in trailing characters, as others have done.

```
\b^(0?[1-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will also pass for when leading zero is not there. Example: 1:11:11

```
(0?[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think this is the best regex

```
data-inputmask-regex="^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):?[0-5]\d$/
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think regex is the right solution for this problem. Sure, it COULD be done, but it just seems wrong.

Make sure your string is four characters long, or 5 characters with a colon in the middle. Then, parse each side and make sure that the left side is less than 24 and the right hand is less than 60.

The regex solution is just so much more complicated.

Comment: Have you not read the other posts? There were numerous attempts, and barely ANYONE got the solution correct (or even understood the problem entirely). My solution is pretty hard to mess up in any language or implementation.

Comment: Oh, there are plenty of ways to mess up your solution, too.  Especially if you're trying to type fast like we were.

Comment: Plenty of WAYS to mess it up? Sure. Easy to mess up? No. Easy to spot a mistake? Yes. Regex? No.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `':'` if the string has one, then if the string is of the form `"DDDD"`, convert it into an `int` and compare it to 2400.

Comment: 2380 is invalid. You have to compare both sides as I suggested.