# How to parse a date in format "YYYYmmdd" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

This is a noob question:

How to parse a date in format `"YYYYmmdd"` without external libraries ? If the input string is not in this format I would like to get `invalid Date` (or undefined if it will be easier).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2587398/650884

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
function parse(str) {
    if(!/^(\d){8}$/.test(str)) return "invalid date";
    var y = str.substr(0,4),
        m = str.substr(4,2),
        d = str.substr(6,2);
    return new Date(y,m,d);
}
```

Usage:

```
parse('20120401');
```

**UPDATE:**

As Rocket said, months are 0-based in js...use this if month's aren't 0-based **in your string**

```
function parse(str) {
    if(!/^(\d){8}$/.test(str)) return "invalid date";
    var y = str.substr(0,4),
        m = str.substr(4,2) - 1,
        d = str.substr(6,2);
    return new Date(y,m,d);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

More rigorous checking for validity of date. Adopted HBP's way to validate date.

```
function parse(str) {
    var y = str.substr(0,4),
        m = str.substr(4,2) - 1,
        d = str.substr(6,2);
    var D = new Date(y,m,d);
    return (D.getFullYear() == y && D.getMonth() == m && D.getDate() == d) ? D : 'invalid date';
}
```

Comment: Note: in JavaScript, months are zero-indexed, so you may want to use `new Date(y, m-1, d);`, otherwise `20120401` will be May 1st, not April 1st.

Comment: What if the input is `00005050`? It is invalid string but `new Date('0000', '50', 50')` is `Tue Jun 09 1903 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (IDT)`

Comment: all right...one more update coming up...if you still have problems, do tell them so that i can improve this answer...actually i did think of this, but thought this might be a trivial case, hence didn't add any code for __detailed__ validation...

Comment: @ParthThakkar Thanks. However now it gets complicated. I wonder if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: All right...another update coming up...this time, I've adopted HBP's way to validate date, much simpler and easier to understand! An upvote to HBP!

Comment: @ParthThakkar—note that the date can be validated by just checking the month (per HBP's answer).

Answer (score 6):

A more robust version validating the numbers :

```
 function parse (str) {
        // validate year as 4 digits, month as 01-12, and day as 01-31 
        if ((str = str.match (/^(\d{4})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$/))) {
           // make a date
           str[0] = new Date (+str[1], +str[2] - 1, +str[3]);
           // check if month stayed the same (ie that day number is valid)
           if (str[0].getMonth () === +str[2] - 1)
              return str[0];
        }
        return undefined;
 }
```

See fiddle at : http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/zJ7dM/

I recently wrote a much more capable version you can find here : http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/Db3JM/

Comment: Great, but instead of returning *undefined* where parsing fails, it should return an invalid date, i.e. `new Date(NaN)`.

Comment: To do this replace the `return undefined` with `return date(NaN)`

Answer (score 3):

simplistic answer maybe, without checks, but fast...

```
var date = parseInt(date);
new Date(date / 10000, date % 10000 / 100, date % 100);
```

or, if months are not zero based in the source,

```
new Date(date / 10000, (date % 10000 / 100) - 1, date % 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using newer language features for destructuring assignment:

```js
// Parse YYYYMMDD to Date
function parseYMD(s) {
  let [C,Y,M,D] = s.match(/\d\d/g);
  return new Date(C+Y, M-1, D);
}

['20211125', // Valid date
 '2021112',  // Invalid input
 '20219999'  // Invalid date components
].forEach(d => 
  console.log(`${d} -> ${parseYMD(d).toDateString()}`)
);
```

Note that this does not validate the date components, any string with 8 or more digits will produce a valid Date. Anything else will produce an invalid Date. If strict parsing is required, consider:

```js
// Parse YYYYMMDD to Date. If any part is out of
// range, return an invalid Date.
function parseYMD(s) {
  let [C,Y,M,D] = s.match(/\d\d/g);
  let d = new Date(C+Y, M-1, D);
  let [yr,mo,da] = d.toLocaleDateString('en-CA').split(/\D/); 
  if (yr != C+Y || mo != M || da != D) {
    d.setTime(NaN);
  }
  return d;
}

['20211125', // Valid date
 '2021112',  // Invalid input
 '20219999'  // Invalid date components
].forEach(d => 
  console.log(`${d} -> ${parseYMD(d).toDateString()}`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

combining HBP's answer and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1494700/1293033) to get a function that parses YYYYMMDDHHmm and here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orrgal/x4touoLd/2/)

```
var parseTS=function(str){
                // validate year as 4 digits, month as 01-12, and day as 01-31
                if ((str = str.match (/^(\d{4})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])([01]\d|2[0-3])([0-5]\d)$/))) {
                    // make a date
                    str[0] = new Date (+str[1], +str[2] - 1, +str[3], +str[4], +str[5]);
                    // check if month stayed the same (ie that day number is valid)
                    if (str[0].getMonth () === +str[2] - 1) {
                        return str[0];
                    }
                }
                return undefined;
            };

    console.log(parseTS('201501012645'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    function parse(str) {
      const year = str.substring(0, 4)
      const month = str.substring(4, 6)
      const day = str.substring(6, 8)
      return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`)
    }
```