# While converting date string into Date object getting NaN-NaN-NaN in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, date

Jquery + rails 4 + Mac + Safari

```
<script>
      function get_next_week_schedule(pre_date_index){
       var date = $('#next_week_'+ pre_date_index).attr('value');
       alert(date); //2014-06-02
       var myDate = new Date(date);
       alert(myDate); // NaN-NaN-NaN
      }
</script>
```

This script is running on Mozilla and crome but while using Mac OS and Safari Browser its showing NaN-NaN-NaN while conversion of date string to Date Object.

Answer (score 1):

The date format is parsed based on locale settings on different browsers. Need to write your own parsing function or get a javascript datetime library.
see this [How to parse a date in format "YYYYmmdd" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638529/how-to-parse-a-date-in-format-yyyymmdd-in-javascript)