# How can I convert a 8 digit number to date format

Tags: javascript

I have a 5 digit number stored in a variable. The next step is to convert the number to a date. for example

```
var x = 20151506;
```

The above number has to be converted to:

```
Thu June 15 2015 06:35:50
```

Comment: Where is the time comming from?

Comment: Do you have some code to start with to show us?

Comment: Where's the 5 digit number?

Comment: That's an 8 digit number.

Comment: The [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) supports multiple parameters.  Just split up your value into pieces and pass each piece in (`new Date(year, month, day)`).

Comment: That's impossible, unless the time part is calculated otherwise.

Comment: The number looks like just the date part in yyyyddmm format. no time info

Comment: exactly its a date format. Its coming from an object.

Comment: when i try something like this:                                                                 new Date(20152605)
Thu Jan 01 1970 06:35:52 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time). It give me a wrong value.

Comment: @AjayKumarHolla: That's because it's expecting your value to be a timestamp.

Comment: @RocketHazmat so what can be the best solution can u put up.

Comment: So regular expression, match the parts, turn it into a date... Not sure houw you get a time from that data...

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you must first specify the time in your original date value for it to be formatted and included correctly in your output. Thus the following will not provide the time element as you're looking for.

Referencing this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10638617/2272357):

```
function parse(str) {
    var y = str.substr(0,4),
        m = str.substr(6,2) - 1,
        d = str.substr(4,2);
    var D = new Date(y,m,d);
    return (D.getFullYear() == y && D.getMonth() == m && D.getDate() == d) ? D : 'invalid date';
}
```

Usage:

`parse('20151506');`

Output:

`Mon Jun 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

or in your case

`parse(x.toString());`

Output:

`Mon Jun 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

Code snippet provided below:

```js
var x = 20151506;

function parse(str) {
    var y = str.substr(0,4),
        m = str.substr(6,2) - 1,
        d = str.substr(4,2);
    var D = new Date(y,m,d);
    return (D.getFullYear() == y && D.getMonth() == m && D.getDate() == d) ? D : 'invalid date';
}

 //document.write (parse('20151506')); 
 document.write (parse(x.toString()));
```

Comment: The OP has a number, not a string

Comment: @phuzi no worries, you can just call `.toString`

Comment: `parse(20151506..toString())`

Comment: @HappyCoding: It dosent work in this case. Try in console and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To convert that "number" in to a Date you'll have to split it into the relevant year month day (hours, minutes and seconds appear to be missing).

```
var x = 20151506;
var month = x % 100;
var day = Math.floor(x % 10000 / 100);
var year = Math.floor(x / 10000);
var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day)
```

This will give you the value of date in whateve your local timezone is - `Mon Jun 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`.

Not sure where you get the your time part from?