# Parse ISO 8601 basic datetime format in javascript

Tags: javascript, iso8601, gnome-shell-extensions

I have a date, as returned from a JSON, in the following format:

```
YYYYMMDDThhmmssZ
```

and I want to parse it in Javascript. I found some resources that cataloge this format as ISO-8601 **basic** format, which is slightly different from the **extended** format which looks like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
```

I have found some resources for how to parse the extended format, but so far I haven't found anything for parsing the basic format. Does such functionality exist in the Date module of Javascript, or so I have to use other modules (e.g. Moment)? I am asking because this is not really an option for me, as the application I am developing is a gnome-shell extension and I don't want to have any extra dependencies.

Comment: Is parsing it as a string an option?

Comment: What does this have to do with "gnome-shell-extensions"?!?

Comment: @kyle, no, parsing it as a string is easy. I want it in a Date format, so that I can manipulate it accordingly (i.e. subtract other Dates from it).

Comment: @mike-mccaughan, I need this for a gnome-shell extension (as it is mentioned in the question). I think it is an important piece of information as it emphasises the fact that I don't want to use any extra javascript modules (such as moment.js)

Comment: You should consider mentioning that in the title and/or at the top of the question. The title alone is pretty generic (and a duplicate [of several questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10638529/215552)).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I guess you are right. I will mark my question as duplicate. I had seen these questions earlier, but thought that maybe there is something else existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

If you can't use moment.js and you can rely on the format of your input being as described, then consider parsing it yourself with something like this:

```js
function parseDate(input) {
  return new Date(Date.UTC(
    parseInt(input.slice(0, 4), 10),
    parseInt(input.slice(4, 6), 10) - 1,
    parseInt(input.slice(6, 8), 10),
    parseInt(input.slice(9, 11), 10),
    parseInt(input.slice(11, 13), 10),
    parseInt(input.slice(13,15), 10)
  ));
}

console.log(parseDate('20130208T080910Z'));
```

It's fairly straightforward to slice out the composite parts. The only quirks are that January is the 0-th month (hence the `- 1`) and that the Date constructor assumes your parameters are for local time, so we follow the advice given in the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation:

> **Note:** Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specifed arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use `new Date(`[`Date.UTC(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)`)` with the same arguments.

I left out format checking, but if you need it, you could define a regular expression to check your input (I'd recommend something no more complex than `/^[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z$/`, and then just let `Date.UTC(...)` do its thing).

### Old answer, updated to specify format string explicitly

If you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), it already supports parsing this format:

```js
console.log(moment('20130208T080910Z', 'YYYYMMDDTHHmmssZ'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will show a warning in recent versions on momentjs because you're not passing a format.

Comment: Thanks tavnab, but as I stated in my question, I am trying to avoid modules such as moment

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan, I've updated my answer

Comment: So, I suppose parsing the string is the only way to go? This works for now, thanks for the help @tavnab

Comment: @Nakano glad to help! There are other ways to go, but parsing is the only one that doesn't involve an external module.