# How to work with Highcharts in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, highcharts

I am new to Highcharts and am stuck with a logic that I need to implement.

My `chartSettings` look something like:

```
self.chartSettings = {
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'x',
      spacingBottom: 30,
      spacingTop: 10,
      height: 200
    },
    title: {
      text: null,
      align: 'left',
      margin: 0
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      type:'category',
      tickInterval:1,
      crosshair: true,
      labels: {
        rotation: 0
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
    min:0,
    title: {
        text: null
    }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
          marker: {
              enabled: false
          }
      },
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    tooltip:{
    shared: true
    }
};
```

I am using `xAxis type category`.

Now, I have 10 days data from `2018/04/30` to `2018/05/09` but as `30th April` falls in April **along with the date names in xAxis I want to show the month name line breaker**

something like:

[image]

My sample data looks like:

```
    "value": [
        {
        "Year": 2018,
        "TimePeriodInYear": 20180430,
        "AnalysisData":2300,
        "StartDate": 20180430,
        "EndDate": 20180430
        },
        {
        "Year": 2018,
        "TimePeriodInYear": 20180501,
        "AnalysisData":2705,
        "StartDate": 20180501,
        "EndDate": 20180501
        },
        ....
        ....
```

I am deducing the `date` from `TimePeriodInYear` and showing as xAxis data points.
But how do I get the month name ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* use categories to display time and date in highcharts, there is a better way. Use a datetime axis, and make sure that you give time in milliseconds for your values.

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10638617/8376046) by [Parth Thakkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975271/parth-thakkar), you can use the following function to parse yyyymmdd to a millisecond number:

```
function parse(number) {
    let str = number.toString()
    let y = str.substr(0,4),
    m = str.substr(4,2) - 1,
    d = str.substr(6,2);
    return new Date(y,m,d).getTime();
}
```

And set type to `datetime`:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime', 
  tickInterval: 3600*24*1000, //tickinterval = 24 hours
  ...
}
```

Then you can use [`xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) to chose how to display your dates.

In addition to that, I set [`useUTC`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.useUTC) to false, to keep local timezone in the chart:

```
time: {
  useUTC: false  //Using local user timezone (instead of UTC)
}
```

**Working example**: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/4vava584/4/