# regExp for HH:mm format including intermediate value

Tags: regex

I am trying to compose a regExp that accepts `HH:mm` time formats, but also accepts all of the intermediate values:

e.g. all of these are accepted:

```
0
1
12
12:
12:3
12:30
1:
1:3
1:30
```

For now, I came up with  this: `^([\d]{1,2}):?([\d]{1,2})?$`

But this accepts any numeric 1/2 digit values for hours and minutes (e.g. `25:66` is acceptable)

So I came relatively close to my goal, but I need to filter out values `x>24` from the hours, and `x>60` from the minutes?

Comment: Perhaps like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494671/regular-expression-for-matching-time-in-military-24-hour-format

Comment: probably, you can build a regex pattern for your requirement. But, regex is not a good tool if you need to do math-calc. I suggest splitting the input by `:` and check the hour and minutes. It would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for

```js
^(?:[01]\d?|2[0-3]?)(?::(?:[0-5]\d?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WiFPjb/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A%5B01%5D%5Cd%3F%7C2%5B0-3%5D%3F)(%3F%3A%3A(%3F%3A%5B0-5%5D%5Cd%3F)%3F)%3F%24):

[image]

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[01]\d?|2[0-3]?)` - either a `0` or `1` followed by an  optional digit, or a `2` followed with an optional `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`
- `(?::(?:[0-5]\d?)?)?` - an optional sequence of patterns:

  - `:` - a  colon
  - `(?:[0-5]\d?)?` - an optional sequence of patterns:

    - `[0-5]` - a digit from `1` to `5`
    - `\d?` - an optional digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer with the explanation as well <3

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`^((?:[01][0-9]?)|(?:2[0-4]?)|(?:[3-9]))(?::((?:[0-5][0-9]?)|(?:60))|:)?$`

**NOTE**:

This accepts `24` for `HH` and `60` for `MM` as stated in your question:

> but I need to filter out values `x>24` from the hours, and `x>60` from the minutes?

Thus ff. are accepted:

```
0
1
12
12:
12:3
12:30
1:
1:3
1:30
1:60
24:60
24:00
00:60
```

and below are not accepted:

```
25:30
00:61
```

[Regex DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/hj1JOW/1)

If you want to exclude `24 HH` and `60 MM`, try this instead:

`^((?:[01]\d?)|(?:2[0-3]?))(?::|(?::([0-5][0-9]?)))?$`

[Regex DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/zSy5vr/1)

### Groups (applies to both cases):

- `\1 = HH`
- `\2 = MM`